# RDL (Report Definition Language) how can i generate 2 tables after one automatically

Tags: c#, report, rdl

I'd like to generate 2 tables in RDL Version 4. I generate 2 tables in c# and i add these tables to an another table. these tables must be after the other table.

I'd like that the tables come after the others. But a table doesn't have "cangrow" property.

[Problem][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfwwA.jpg

I'd like this: [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xU7lA.jpg
[solution]

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an answer, you need to make the tables in a subreport. A table in a Subreport and an another table to the another subreport. And then you can use the 2 two subreport in a Report. These method can you in c# too.